# ansible to provision azure loadbalncer with private ip

Tags: azure, ansible

I was trying to provision an Azure load-balancer with only a private IP address in an existing subnet. I could accomplish this with the below code.

```
 - name: create load balancer
  azure_rm_loadbalancer:
    resource_group: "{{resource_group_name}}"
    name: my_new_lb
    frontend_ip_configurations:
      - name: frontendipconf0
        private_ip_address:
        private_ip_allocation_method: dynamic
       subnet: /subscriptions/1234445sdffew11111111/resourceGroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-stage/subnets/default
    backend_address_pools:
      - name: backend_pool1
    probes:
      - name: prob0
        port: 80
    load_balancing_rules:
      - name: lbrbalancingrule0
        frontend_ip_configuration: frontendipconf0
        backend_address_pool: backend_pool1
        frontend_port: 8000
        backend_port: 443
        probe: prob0
```

But is there a way we can provision a loadbalancer without providing a complete subnet id in the task file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to provision the load balancer with a private IP address, then you must associate a subnet to the load balancer, so I think an existing subnet resource id is necessary. It's impossible not to provide a complete subnet id in the task file.

**Update:**

Here is the example to get the virtual network info:

```
- name: Get the Load Balancer info
  azure_rm_virtualnetwork_info:
    resource_group: "{{ resource_group_name }}" 
    name: "{{ vnet_name }}" 
  register: vnet
```

Then you can input the subnet id in the load balancer like this:

```
subnet: "{{ vnet.virtualnetworks[0].subnets[0].id }}"
```

You can get the VNet info and change the subnet you want to use. Please read the [`azure_rm_virtualnetwork_info` example](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/azure_rm_virtualnetwork_info_module.html#examples) carefully.

Comment: Thanks for the updated @charles, I know a subnet is required for LB, but am looking for an option instead of giving complete resource ID any other option to pass this value. For example in the MSFT doc for appgateway https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/ansible/application-gateway-configure?tabs=ansible they passed subnet value as ```- subnet:
              id: "{{ subnet.response[0].id }}"

Comment: @Techiescorner So you can use the same thing [`azure_rm_resource_facts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/ansible/application-gateway-configure?tabs=ansible#create-the-application-gateway) to get the subnet id, or use the thing [`azure_rm_virtualnetwork_info`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/azure_rm_virtualnetwork_info_module.html#azure-rm-virtualnetwork-info-module) to get the subnet id.  Is there anything you can't understand?

Comment: Tried multiple times but getting Unsupported parameters for (azure_rm_virtualnetwork_info) module error.

- name: Get info of Subnet
  azure_rm_virtualnetwork_info:
    api_version: '2018-08-01'
    resource_group: "{{ resource_group_name }}"
    virtualnetworks:
      - name: "{{ vnet_name }}"
    subnets:
      - name: "{{ subnet_name }}"
    register: subnet

- name: create load balancer
  azure_rm_loadbalancer:
    resource_group: "{{resource_group_name}}"

Comment: Thanks a lot, Charles for your updated answer

Comment: @Techiescorner Well, if it works for you, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve the issue with the help of azure_rm_resource_info as well. Adding the script below.

```
azure_rm_resource_info:
    api_version: '2018-08-01'
    resource_group: "{{ resource_group_name }}"
    provider: network
    resource_type: virtualnetworks
    resource_name: "{{ vnet_name }}"
    subresource:
      - type: subnets
        name: "{{ subnet_name }}"
  register: subnet
- name: create load balancer
  azure_rm_loadbalancer:
    resource_group: "{{resource_group_name}}"
    name: lb_name
    frontend_ip_configurations:
      - name: frontendipconf0
        private_ip_address:
        private_ip_allocation_method: dynamic
        subnet: "{{subnet.response[0].id }}"
```